# I need to set the center of the circle to user's current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code that let the user set the radius of the circle through input box and button. What I need to do is to set the center of the circle to the user's current location. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false">
 
    <head>

     
    <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map-canvas { width:100%;height:80%; }
    .controls      
    </style>
    

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX"></script>


    <script>


    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
    var circle;

    function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
    });
    
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 100,    // 10 miles in metres
        fillColor: '#AA0000',
        center: myCenter
     });               
    marker.setMap(map);    

    }

    function updateRadius(){
    var rad = document.getElementById("value_rad").value;
    circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));
    }
    

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    console.log()

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:80%;"></div>
    <input id="value_rad" />
    <input id="radius" type="button" value="Search" onclick="updateRadius()"/>
    </body>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called Geolocation, there's a good writeup here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

You'll need to grab the users latitude and longitude within the success callback for 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

Eg

```
function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(crd.latitude, crd.longitude);
    // init map and whatnot
};
```

You'll need to do some checks to ensure that fetching the users location is allowed, there are references to that in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to geolocate the user (which requires the user to agree to share his/her position):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //rest of function
    });
}
```

Note - to do this on Chrome, you will need to use https.